# I can't find the created template in Dreamweaver CS6

Tags: web, dreamweaver

I created a template and saved it into my site root folder. But when I want to create new page from that template I can't find it in the template list of my site.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store it on the `Templates` folder under your the site's root folder.

How about [having a look at the documentation](http://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/using/creating-dreamweaver-template.html)?